# loop for -javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

what is the problem of this loop?

```
    for(i=0; i<18; i++)
    {
        $("'#various'+i+1").fancybox({
Something
            });
        }
```

it is supposed to be various1, various2, etc

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#various"+(i+1)).fancybox({
```

Answer (score 1):

The `i` variable needs to be outside the quotes.

```
for(i=1; i<=18; i++) {
    $("#various"+i).fancybox({  /*...*/ });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is bad syntax in your string concatenation.

```
for(var i=1; i<19; i++) {
    $('#various'+i).fancybox({
       'Something':'val'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 18; i++){
    $('#various' + (i + 1)).fancybox({
       // something
    });
}
```